# How to setup a python environment in an OS/X app?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

I'm a newbie to Obj-C so please be patient with me, but I try to build an OSX Wrapper around an Python Script. I want the app to download a script and then execute it, but the problem is that their some dependencies for example: `pycurl`.

Now I want to setup an little Python environment inside of my app, so the user doesn't have to care about dependencies and so on...

Any Idea how to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtualenv. Install it with pip

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

then in your directory

```
$ cd mydir
$ virtualenv .
$ ./bin/pip install package1 package2 etc
$ ./bin/python
```

When you want to share the list of python packages used, do

```
$ ./bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If you want to install everything in a new environment, do

```
$ ./bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will works in Mac OS X, Windows and Linux.